# How to get total count using getGridParam() after trigger("reloadGrid")

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to check total count about records after search.
But `getGridParam("records")` not run after `trigger("reloadGrid")`.

Here is my code.

```
goSearch : function() {
    var jsonObj = {};
    var $jqGrid = $("#jqGrid");

    if ($("#selectId").val() != "c") {
        jsonObj.serviceImplYn = $("#selectId").val();
    }

    $jqGrid.setGridParam({
        datatype        : "json",
        postData        : {"param" : JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        loadComplete    : function(data) {

            if (data.rows.length < 1) {
                alert("no data.");
            }
        }
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");

    //following line not running! first run value = 0, second = success
    var totalCnt = $jqGrid.getGridParam("records");

    console.log(totalCnt);
}
```

How to get total count in first `goSearch()` run?

Comment: Your current code execute `var totalCnt = $jqGrid.getGridParam("records");` after **starting** Ajax request, which loads the data from the server, but **before** the data are loaded. You should just move the line `var totalCnt = $jqGrid.getGridParam("records");` inside of `loadComplete`, which will be executed *after* the data are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should either run the command

```
var totalCnt = $jqGrid.getGridParam("records");
```

in loadComplete you post

```
$jqGrid.setGridParam({
    datatype        : "json",
    postData        : {"param" : JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
    loadComplete    : function(data) {

        if (data.rows.length < 1) {
            alert("no data.");
        }
        var totalCnt = $jqGrid.getGridParam("records");
    }
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

or run it in setTmeout function to wait until ajax request is made to load the data, so you can get the needed info.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var totalCnt = $jqGrid.getGridParam("records");
}, 300);
```